# C++ conversion operator to chrono::duration - works with c++17 but not C++14 or less

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-chrono, conversion-operator, c++17

The following code compiles with gcc 7.1.0 with C++17 set but does not compile with C++14 set (or Visual Studio 2017). It is easy to reproduce on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b8QJGuSPUcTPRuFM).

What has to be done to make it work with C++11/14?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    struct Convert
    {
        operator std::chrono::milliseconds()
        {
            std::cout << "operator std::chrono::milliseconds" << std::endl;
            return std::chrono::milliseconds(10);
        }

        operator int64_t ()
        {
            std::cout << "operator int64_t" << std::endl;
            return 5;
        }
    };

    Convert convert;

    std::chrono::milliseconds m(convert);
    std::cout << m.count() << std::endl;
    int64_t i(convert);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the ins and out of it but if you make your two functions `const` it compiles for me. (after adding the missing parts)

Comment: It also compiles if I don't make them `const` but I do make them `explicit`. Again, don't know the ins and outs of it.

Comment: please post the compiler error message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with why this doesn't work in C++14. There are two relevant c'tors for [`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) (which `std::chrono::milliseconds` is aliased to be):

```
duration( const duration& ) = default;

template< class Rep2 >
constexpr explicit duration( const Rep2& r );
```

The templated one is a much better match for an argument of type `Convert`. But it will only participate in overload resolution if `Rep2` (a.k.a `Convert`) is implicitly convertible to the representation type of `std::chrono::duration`. For `milliseconds`, that is `long` on Wandbox. Your `int64_t` conversion operator makes that implicit conversion possible.

But here's the catch. The check for this implicit conversion doesn't take the cv-qualifiers of the conversion member function into account. So that overload is chosen, but it accepts by a const reference. And your user defined conversion operator is not `const` qualified! [@Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik) noted it in the comments to your post. As such, the conversion fails inside the c'tor of `milliseconds`.

So how to resolve it? Two ways:

1. Mark the conversion operator `const`. That will however pick the conversion to `int64_t` for both `m` and `i`.
2. Mark the conversion to `int64_t` as `explicit`. Now the templated overload won't participate in overload resolution for `m`.

And finally, why does this work in C++17? That would be guaranteed copy elision. Since your `Convert` has a conversion to `std::chrono::milliseconds`, it is used to initialized `m` directly. The minutia of it involves not even needing to choose the copy constructor, just to elide it later.

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty interesting case. The reason it fails to compile on C++14 is correctly explained by [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48365910/2069064), and is arguably an LWG defect - the requirement on the converting constructor is that [`Rep2` is convertible to `rep`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration.cons#1), but the body of that constructor attempts to convert a `Rep2 const` to `rep` - and in the particular example in OP, this is ill-formed. This is now [LWG 3050](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3050).

In C++17 though, none of the relevant, articulated rules in the standard have changed. Direct-initialization (e.g. `std::chrono::milliseconds m(convert);`) still just considers [constructors](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2), and the best match from overload resolution amongst the constructors would still be the very same defective converting constructor that causes the program to fail to compilein C++14.

*However*, there is an outstanding core issue that both gcc and clang have apparently decided to implement, despite there not being wording for it yet. Consider:

```
struct A 
{ 
  A(); 
  A(const A&) = delete; 
}; 
struct B 
{ 
  operator A(); 
}; 

B b; 
A a1 = b; // OK 
A a2(b);  // ?
```

Per the language rules today, copy-initializing from `b` is okay, we use the conversion function. But direct-initializing from `b` is not okay, we would have to use `A`'s deleted copy constructor.

Another motivating example is:

```
struct Cat {};
struct Dog { operator Cat(); };

Dog d;
Cat c(d);
```

Here, again, we'd have to go through `Cat(Cat&& )` - which in this case is well-formed, but inhibits copy elision due to [temporary materialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.2.1).

So the suggested resolution of this issue is to consider *both* constructors *and* conversion functions for direct-initialization. In both examples here and in the OP's example, this would yield the "expected" behavior - direct-initialization would just use the conversion function as being the better match. Both gcc and clang take this route in C++17 mode, which is why the examples compiles today.