# Call of overloaded static_cast is ambiguous

Tags: c++, static-cast

I have some code like this

```
struct B
{
    B() {}
    B(int v) {}
};

struct A
{
    operator int() const { return 1; }
    operator B() const { return B(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    static_cast<B>(a); // Error here
    a.operator B(); // This is OK
    return 0;
}
```

It produces such compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:21: error: call of overloaded ‘B(A&)’ is ambiguous
     static_cast<B>(a);
                     ^
main.cpp:4:5: note: candidate: B::B(int)
     B(int v) {}
     ^
main.cpp:1:8: note: candidate: constexpr B::B(const B&)
 struct B
        ^
main.cpp:1:8: note: candidate: constexpr B::B(B&&)
```

I don't ask how to fix this. Just want to understand why compiler doesn't take it? From my POV `static_cast<B>(a)` is equal with `a.operator B()` but seems compilator reads it differently.

**Update:**

This behavior happens pre c++17. With c++17 this code doesn't produce any compilation error.

Comment: `static_cast<B>(a)` could potentially either mean `B(a.operator int())` or `a.operator B()`

Comment: Although I don't get any error in g++ 7.2, it selects `a.operator B()` for the `static_cast`

Comment: Making (at least) `operator int` `explicit` would fix it and probably be a good idea. g++ suggests this is fine in C++17 though.

Comment: @M.M you're right no error with -std=c++1z but with -std=c++14 error is present

Comment: I imagine GCC 7.2 accepting it with `-std=c++1z` has something to do with the background provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48384896/817643). I.e., GCC's take on guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: This also happens in VS2017. It gets wierder `B b = static_cast<B>(a);` ambiguous while `B b = a;` is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## C++14

According to N3797 [expr.static.cast] paragraph 4:

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

The expression `static_cast<B>(a)` performs a direct-initialization of a temporary variable of type `B` from the initializer `a`. Then the following bullet from N3797 [dcl.init] paragraph 17 applies:

> If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. **The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3).** The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or *expression-list* as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

And "applicable constructors" are defined by N3797 [over.match.ctor]:

> For direct-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized.

So all the three constructors: `B::B(int)`, `B::B(const B&)`, `B::B(B&&)` are candidates during overload resolution. Then three corresponding implicit conversion sequences: `A->int`, `A->const B&`, `A->B&&` are compared. As a result, `A->int` is distinguishable from the other two since the conditions of the following bullet from N3797 [over.ics.rank] paragraph 3 are not met:

> User-defined conversion sequence `U1` is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence `U2` if **they contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor** or they initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization and in either case the second standard conversion
>   sequence of U1 is better than the second standard conversion sequence of `U2`.

In addition, no special rules of determining the best viable function in N3797 [over.match.best] paragraph 1 apply, so the overload resolution is ambiguous, which causes the compiler error.

## C++17

The deduction above also holds, so this is a compiler bug (for now). The wording for [expr.static.cast] paragraph 4 has changed due to [CWG 242](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#242), but it does not affect our conclusion.

Note guaranteed copy elision does not apply here because it is not an initialization from a prvalue of the same type.

## C++20 or later

There is already a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/rpOG44MGH7s/n55SAATcBgAJ) about adding guaranteed copy elision to such direct-initialization cases, so maybe the behavior of selecting `a.operator B()` will be legal in the future.

Comment: In short this means. Compiler for expression `static_cast<B>(a);` finds two substitutions: `B(a.operator int())` and `B(a.operator B())`. But `a.operator B()` is not a substitution. This is correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the rules of `direct initialization` (wrt `copy elision` in particular) are slightly altered in C++17, and `static_cast<B>(a);` simply results in:

```
a.operator B();
```

As mentioned on [cppreference/direct_initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

> if the initializer is a prvalue expression whose type is the same class as T (ignoring cv-qualification), the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see copy elision (since C++17)

And when reading further in [cppreference/copy_elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), it says that since C++17, the compilers are required to omit the copy- and move- construction if

> In a function call, if the operand of a return statement is a prvalue and the return type of the function is the same as the type of that prvalue.

Thus, while `static_cast<B>(a);` pre C++17 can be interpreted both as `B(a.operator int())` and `a.operator B()`, C++17 has to pick the second option, since the return value of `a.operator B()` is `prvalue` of type `B` and it can omit copy-/move- construction.

Comment: *if the initializer is a prvalue expression **whose type is the same class as T...*** Why does this bullet apply instead of the next one: *the constructors of T are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.*

Comment: @xskxzr, not sure that the rules are always listed in prioritized order, but even without that - opting for not calling a constructor instead of selecting the best match seems reasonable.

Comment: [These rules **are** listed in prioritized order](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6). [Also your idea of such elision's being reasonable is essentially CWG 2327](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696012/5376789).